# CORS preflight OPTIONS request returning error, but POST still being sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, cross-domain, cors

I'm making a cross-domain request to an asmx service from my site using jQuery ajax as follows:

```
$j.ajax({
  url: svcURL,
  type: "POST",
  data: xml,
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(d) {
    alert(d);
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

This `POST` request is preceded by a preflight `OPTIONS` request which the service is not configured to deal with currently, so it returns with either a `500 (Internal Server Error)` or a `405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

After receiving this error, I would expect the browser to then ignore the `POST` request and return an error, however:

**In Chrome & IE** the `POST` request is still sent (which the service is correctly configured to deal with) and a response is received.

**In Firefox** the `POST` just returns an error.

Could someone explain the reason why this works in Chrome? I would have expected it to behave how Firefox does.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the OPTIONS request is actually being triggered? Do you see it returning a response in the network tab or firebug?

Comment: Yeah, I can see the OPTIONS request being sent in the Console/Fiddler. With the current service I'm using I get a 405 Error response. The subsequent POST then works in Chrome, but returns an error in Firefox.

Comment: I have a page for testing CORS requests. When I try making a POST request with `Content-Type: text/xml`, I get an error: 

http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=POST&client_credentials=false&client_headers=Content-Type%3A%20text%2Fxml&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_methods=POST&server_tabs=local

Do you see the same behavior? Note how the OPTIONS request is rejected in Chrome's network browser.

Comment: I've configured my service to allow Content-Type headers, so I don't see the same behaviour as you.
For my request Chrome's console shows:
`OPTIONS http://website.com/svc.asmx 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: When the request succeeds in Chrome, is the `Content-Type` header still `text/xml`? Maybe it downgrades the request to a simple request that doesn't require a preflight. (That seems like a really dumb thing for the browser to do, but maybe jQuery does it?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just checked this and the successful request still has `Content-Type: text/xml` in the headers. The service requires the `Content-Type` to be set so a simple request always returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139566) and [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92755) that sends the subsequent request even if the `OPTIONS` request fails.

Firefox follows the CORS spec correctly and cancels the request once the preflight fails.